# Is it possible to modify an element in an infinite list?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a list of zeroes:

```
zeroes = repeat 0
```

And I'd like to modify the nth member of that list. Is there a built in for this, or some function I could write to do it? Is this possible in the first place?

Note: Yes, I know you can't really modify anything in haskell without a state monad, so treat it as meaning "construct a new list exactly identical to but different by one element".

Comment: "Access Nth element of a list" typically means you probably don't want to use a list (for performance reasons). Depending what you're trying to do, of course...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
(take (n-1) zeroes) ++ [desired_nth_member] ++ (drop n zeroes)
```

Comment: Of course, if `zeroes` is really infinite, then `drop n zeroes == zeroes` :)

Comment: @chepner: The OP did specify that the list is infinite, but did *not* specify that all the elements are the same; `zeroes` seems to be just an example.

Comment: You can also replace `take` + `drop` with `splitAt` and save a traversal.

Answer (score 3):

Or using [Lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Data-List-Lens.html):

```
import Control.Lens

setNth :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
setNth = set . ix
```

For example:

```
> take 10 $ setNth 3 42 (repeat 0)
[0,0,0,42,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Actually you don't really need a function:

```
> take 10 $ (repeat 0) & ix 3 .~ 42
[0,0,0,42,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Note that this can work with [a lot more types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:Ixed) than just lists:

```
setNth :: Ixed t => Index t -> IxValue t -> t -> t

> setNth 1 42 (0,0,0)
(0,42,0)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and kudos for an excellent first answer!

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
setNth :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
setNth n val = zipWith insert [0..]
  where insert i x | i == n = val
                   | otherwise = x

> take 10 . setNth 5 2 $ repeat 0
[0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: For point-free fans, `insert = bool id (const val) . (== n)`.